# complex sql update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

The table MyTable contains 4 columns.

- id, phone columns are unique.
- id, phone, zipcode are never empty.

---

```
id - phone -        salary   - zipcode

1  - 61730459987 - $56052.45 - 02456

2 - 21249620709 - NULL -      10023

3 - 21200830859 - $39089.28 - 10023

...

10000 - 64600830857 - $46063.72 - 03795**
```

I need to remove NULLs by replacing them with salary_estimates, based on information from the same zip-codes.

As for the example above, NULL at row #2 could be replaced with $39089.28 (we can find from the table that another person with the same zip-code 10023 earns $39089.28, so it's OK to update NULL for #2 with $39089.28).
So, after we run this query, the number of empty cells could be reduced (although not up to zero).

Could anybody suggest an update query for this problem?

Comment: is my answer solve your problem or not ?

Comment: Upendra Chaudhari, I've tried to change your answer so it fits for MySQL, not for MSSQL... Moving "top 1" as "limit 1" to the end of select query and some other changes didn't help. I'm sorry.  Ypercube user wrote a perfect answer that works as I expected. He even guessed that I probably need an AVG function. Question was resolved on 100.%. Thank you very much everybody for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE
      MyTable AS tu
  JOIN 
      ( SELECT zipcode
             , AVG(salary) AS SalaryEstimate          --- AVG, MAX, MIN
                                                      --- your choice
        FROM MyTable 
        WHERE salary IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY zipcode
      ) AS te
    ON te.zipcode = tu.zipcode
SET 
      tu.salary = te.SalaryEstimate
WHERE 
      tu.salary IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it will work for mysql. But in MSSQL you can do like this :

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET salary = (select top 1 salary from MyTable where zipcode = t1.zipcode and salary is not null)
FROM MyTable t1 
WHERE t1.salary is null
```

You need to check equivalent join case for mysql.

**Ref. Test Query :**

```
create table #temp (id int, salary decimal(18,2), zipcode varchar(10))
insert into #temp values (1,56052.45,02456)
insert into #temp values (2,NULL,1023)
insert into #temp values (3,39089.28,1023)
insert into #temp values (4,46063.72,03795)
insert into #temp values (5,NULL,02456)

UPDATE #temp
SET salary = (select top 1 salary from #temp where zipcode = t1.zipcode and salary is not null)
FROM #temp t1 
WHERE t1.salary is null

select * from #temp
drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this: if `salary` is null it will replace with salary of that zipcode.

```
isnull(salary,(Select top 1 salary  from  MyTable  where zipcode=10023 ))
```

Comment: Thank you... But, I need to update this table for all zipcodes, not just for 10023.

Comment: Zipcode value will come dynamically as in your example for row one "02456"  will be in query. you will get data for zip code you need to add same in Query.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what an update query you suggest me to use. The table is MyTable. 4 columns: id, phone,salary and zipcode. What sql string do you recommend me to execute? Thank you.

Comment: update table mytable set id=@ID ,Phone=@phone,salary=(ISNULL(@salary,(Select top 1 salary  from  MyTable  where zipcode=@zipcode )),zipcode=@zipcode  >> here @id,@phone,@salary,@zipcode is dynamic value.. I am not sure from where you are getting this.., but by this way you can approch for solution.

Comment: For MySQL (I replaced ISNULL with IFNULL and top 1 with limit 1) "update mytable set id=@id, phone=@phone, salary=(IFNULL(@salary,(Select salary from MyTable where zipcode=@zipcode limit 1)), zipcode=@zipcode" says "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax" and does not work.